# Video not fitting inside container despite using fitted box etc

Tags: flutter

I have following code for fitting it video inside container:

**VideoController Code**

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: _initializeMainVideoPlayerFuture,
  builder: (context, snapshot){
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
      return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: _videoMainController.value.aspectRatio,
        child: Opacity(
            opacity: 0.5,
            child: VideoPlayer(_videoMainController)),
      );
    }
    else
    {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          color: kSecondaryColor,
        ),
      );
    }
  },
);
```

**This builder is inside following container in main class:**

```
Positioned(
        top: screenHeight * 0.18,
        left: screenWidth * 0.045,
        child: Container(
          height: videoContainerHeight,
          width: videoContainerWidth,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: kPrimaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
          ),
          child: MainVideoContainer(),
        ),
      ),
```

**Container width and height are:**

```
final double videoContainerHeight = screenHeight / 1.4;
final double videoContainerWidth = screenWidth /1.1;
```

**The results am getting:**
[image]
space from both sides is left like this.

**What I tried?**
I tried using Fitted Box with fit property set to cover, contain and fill but it disappears video and returns plain container, setting aspectRatio to 16/9 tho I dont know how to use AspectRatio properly.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to wrap with Expanded it will resolve your issue.

Comment: No it didnt work. Am already exhausted. Its been a week and no one knows the correct answer.